# lyx- how to add line-delete-backward shortcut mac?

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to add the short cut `line-delete-backward` to LyX and it responds by saying that this function is unknown or invalid, even though there is a `line-delete-forward` function. Does anyone know of this and/or solved this. 
Thanks.
(BTW I'm on mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/lyxgit/src/LyXAction.cpp#L2435), there is a comment saying

```
// there is no line-delete-backward
```

so there is no such function.

But [there seems to be a function `line-begin-select`](https://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/lyxgit/src/LyXAction.cpp#L2426), so perhaps that could be combined with a deleting function, e.g.

```
command-sequence line-begin-select; char-delete-forward;
```

I haven't tested this though, so it might not be of use.